# Using VS2013 and VS2010 with TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We currently have TFS 2010 and mostly work with VS2010. We're gradually starting to use VS2013 with the Express version.

How come when I open the Source Control Explorer in VS2013, everything shows as "Not Mapped" even though it IS mapped? When I try to map something, it gives me *"The path X is already mapped in workspace Y"*

I can't open anything from the Source Control Explorer since it prompts to map, but I manually open the project from the local folder, and see the little lock and + symbols in the solution explorer. I can even do check-ins and undos.

Comment: You should upgrade your TFS server before you fall out of support.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new 2013 server workspace and trying to open it in 2010?

Comment: We'll upgrade to TFS2013 or to the upcoming 2015 early next year. Budget obliges. We're stuck with 2010 for the next few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that source control explorer is connected to the same workspace as VS2010 by looking at the workspace drop down at the top of SCE. If your VS2010 workspace is a server workspace, and you created a new local workspace in VS2013 you'll see two workspace names showing.

Also, when you open an existing solution in Visual Studio, if that solution is in a workspace different than the one source control explorer is currently showing, SCE doesn't switch over automatically. You have to do it manually, again via that workspace drop down.